# warning in Position + IntersectingQ

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, warning-messages

Why there is a warning message (with correct output) for the following code ?

```
Position[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {1, 
   6}}, _?(IntersectingQ[#, {1, 3}] == True &), 1]
```

There is no warning message for the following similar code.

```
Position[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {1, 
       6}}, _?(MemberQ[#, 1] == True &)]
```

a helpful screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the  option `Heads -> False`:

```
Position[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {1, 6}}, 
   _?(IntersectingQ[#, {1, 3}] == True &), 1, 
   Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {4}, {6}}
> ```

[`Heads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I should've read options more carefully, thank you!